# How to disable/enable all textfields in a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This is more a question about best practices. I have a view with many text fields, and I need a method that will toggle between enabling and disabling all text fields simultaneously. One way that I think will work, is the following:

```
- (void)activateTextFields:(BOOL)activate {
    [firstTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:activate];
    [secondTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:activate];
    ...
    [lastTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:activate];
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is better way (given the vast number of fields) to do this with just a single line that will disable/enable all text fields at once.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place a transparent view on top of all the text fields with userInteraction enabled, that would "trap" all taps and stop them from going to the text fields.

Edit: this is probably better: just return NO from this method:

> textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Asks the
>   delegate if editing should begin in
>   the specified text field.
>
> `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField
>   *)textField` Parameters textField The text field for which editing is about
>   to begin. Return Value YES if an
>   editing session should be initiated;
>   otherwise, NO to disallow editing.

That way, there's only one bit of state to change, your class's "shouldTextFieldsAllowEditing" boolean property.

Comment: Interesting idea, but sadly it would cover other things (e.g. sliders) that I still want to be enabled.

Comment: This is great. I can just set a BOOL that changes when I want and then the textfields check the BOOL to see if they should edit. This will be great. Thanks!